# maven-jaxb2-plugin cannot generate classes due to two declarations cause a collision in ObjectFactory class

Tags: java, maven, soap, wsdl

I have created `.wsdl` file in `/src/main/resources/wsdl`. Here I have pasted the the content of the soap wsdl.

I added the following plugin to maven:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.14.0</version>

        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>

                <configuration>
                    <generatePackage>bankup.wsdl</generatePackage>
                    <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
                    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                    <schemaIncludes>
                        <include>*.wsdl</include>
                    </schemaIncludes>
                    <clearOutputDir>true</clearOutputDir>
                </configuration>

            </execution>

        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

The project fails to build due to the error in generating the classes from the wsdl. There are two declarations collesion in the objectFactory class. The error is like below:

```
[ERROR] Error while generating code.Location [ http://uri/ifx?xsd=ws-bankup_schema4.xsd{3125,63}].
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ErrorReceiver.error (ErrorReceiver.java:86)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.ObjectFactoryGeneratorImpl.populate (ObjectFactoryGeneratorImpl.java:191)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.PublicObjectFactoryGenerator.populate (PublicObjectFactoryGenerator.java:59)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.<init> (BeanGenerator.java:272)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generate (BeanGenerator.java:171)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.model.Model.generateCode (Model.java:288)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_3.XJC23Mojo.generateCode (XJC23Mojo.java:66)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_3.XJC23Mojo.doExecute (XJC23Mojo.java:41)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_3.XJC23Mojo.doExecute (XJC23Mojo.java:28)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute (RawXJC2Mojo.java:478)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute (RawXJC2Mojo.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] Error while generating code.Location [ http://uri/ifx?xsd=ws-bankup_schema5.xsd{3,63}].
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.   
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ErrorReceiver.error (ErrorReceiver.java:86)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.ObjectFactoryGeneratorImpl.populate (ObjectFactoryGeneratorImpl.java:193)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.PublicObjectFactoryGenerator.populate (PublicObjectFactoryGenerator.java:59)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.<init> (BeanGenerator.java:272)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generate (BeanGenerator.java:171)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.model.Model.generateCode (Model.java:288)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_3.XJC23Mojo.generateCode (XJC23Mojo.java:66)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_3.XJC23Mojo.doExecute (XJC23Mojo.java:41)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_3.XJC23Mojo.doExecute (XJC23Mojo.java:28)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute (RawXJC2Mojo.java:478)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute (RawXJC2Mojo.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

From the reading the log, I understand that wsdl has many schemes that have collision.

I checked the schemes and saw that 
`schema6` imports `schema4`, and `schema4` import `schema3`, and `schema3` imports `schema2`, and `schema2` imports `schema1`. To prevent the collision I changed the plugin configuration to create schema objects in separated packages. Below it modification i did to plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.14.0</version>
    <executions>

        <execution>
            <id>schema6-genearate</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>schema6.xsd</include>
                </schemaIncludes>
                <generatePackage>bankup.schema6.generated</generatePackage>
                <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc1</generateDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>schema5-genearate</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>schema5.xsd</include>
                </schemaIncludes>
                <generatePackage>bankup.schema5.generated</generatePackage>
                <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc1</generateDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Even though they are being generated in different packages, it still gives me the same error.

```
[ERROR] Error while generating code.Location [ schema4.xsd{3125,63}].
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ErrorReceiver.error (ErrorReceiver.java:86)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.ObjectFactoryGeneratorImpl.populate (ObjectFactoryGeneratorImpl.java:191)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.PublicObjectFactoryGenerator.populate (PublicObjectFactoryGenerator.java:59)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.<init> (BeanGenerator.java:272)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.generator.bean.BeanGenerator.generate (BeanGenerator.java:171)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.model.Model.generateCode (Model.java:288)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_3.XJC23Mojo.generateCode (XJC23Mojo.java:66)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_3.XJC23Mojo.doExecute (XJC23Mojo.java:41)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_3.XJC23Mojo.doExecute (XJC23Mojo.java:28)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute (RawXJC2Mojo.java:478)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute (RawXJC2Mojo.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] Error while generating code.Location [schema5.xsd{3,63}].
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
```

Why is this still happening??
I will appreciate any help, by tomorrow I will put a boundty of 50+ points plus who help me solve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Never generate code int `src/main/java`. The code will generated by default into `target/generated-sources/xjc/<package>` and usually there is no need to configure the plugin in that way. Keep the convention and located your `wsdl` into `src/main/resources` (see the docs https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Specifying-What-To-Compile). Keep convention over configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this issue, you need to create `bind.xjb` file. Create the `bind.xjb` file in the path `src/main/java/bindings`.
In this file we will solve the conflicts that prevent the creation of `ObjectFactory`. What is happining is that 
in you schema you have the `ObjectFactory` declared in `schema6` and `schema5`. So a workaround to this would that this
schema to be generated in separated packages. In the `bind.xjb` file, we will instruct the maven plugin to generate
the classes from `schema5` and `schema6` in different packages. Below it is the code for `bind.xjb` file:

```
<jaxb:bindings version="1.0"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">

    <jaxb:bindings
        schemaLocation="schema6.xsd"
        node="/xs:schema">

        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="bankup.schema6" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>

    </jaxb:bindings>

    <jaxb:bindings
        schemaLocation="schema5.xsd"
        node="/xs:schema">

        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="bankup.schema5" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>

    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

After that you need to configure `bind.xjb` in maven jaxb2 plugin. To do that, you should modify the `maven jaxb2 plugin`
like below:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.14.0</version>
                <executions>

                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>

                        <configuration>
                            <bindingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/bindings</bindingDirectory>
                            <bindingIncludes>
                                <include>bind.xjb</include>
                            </bindingIncludes>
                            <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>*.wsdl</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <clearOutputDir>true</clearOutputDir>
                            <vmArgs>
                                <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
                            </vmArgs>
                        </configuration>

                    </execution>


                </executions>

            </plugin>
```

After running the build, all the classes should be generated in the default directory: `target/generated-sources/xjc`.

Hope this is helpful to you.